# On video close using Youtube player library

Tags: swift, video, youtube, completionhandler

I am using the [library forked from google's youtube implementation that works with Swift 4.](https://github.com/hmhv/YoutubePlayer-in-WKWebView)

I can get videos to work fine within this and it works great.

However, I want to know when the video is being closed and get an "onCloseEventHandler" to do something for me (specifically to direct me to another view controller).

Here is my code so far. I am passing a variable name `video` from another VC that has information about the video.

```swift
import UIKit
import YoutubePlayer_in_WKWebView

class VideoViewController: UIViewController {

    let playerView = WKYTPlayerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadViews() // this just loads my views and sets this up
    }

    var video: Video? = nil {
        didSet {
            updateViews()
        }
    }

    func updateViews() {

        playerView.load(withVideoId: (video?.youtubeId)!)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your application fullscreen video exit or close button press this observer call. This is basically window is a hidden notification. Add this observer in your app delegate, and do whatever you want in videoExitFullScreen function. Translate to swift yourself.

```
// Add status bar notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoExitFullScreen:) name:@"UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification" object:nil];

- (void)videoExitFullScreen:(id)sender
{
 // do whatever you want.
}
```